# Uncaught TypeError:cannot read properties of null reading addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project in which at the forms in input I need to take the input value of email id and console log it so while taking the input value it shows Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

These two images shows the js code to get input value and another images the error in page

[image]

[image]

I am expecting that I need to solve this and I need to get the input value

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
  let Sign_email = document.querySelector('#Sign_email');
  const getInputvalue = () => {
    let userinput = Sign_email.value;
    console.log(userinput)
  }
  btn.addEventListener('click', getInputvalue)
})
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="/sign" class="sign-in-form">
  <h2 class="title">Sign in</h2>
  <div class="input-field">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <input name="Sign_email" id="Sign_email" type="email" placeholder="Email Id" />
  </div>
  <div class="input-field">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    <input name="Sign_password" id="Sign_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <p id="error">Login again</p>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn solid" />

</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I made you a snippet. It works as expected. Please do not post pictures of code

Comment: Lastly use the submit event of the form instead of the click event of the submit button

Answer (score 0):

Your code working good on my end. It would be better if you share line where the error occur

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @mplungjan - Sorry I tried to find the comment button. I didn't find that. Now I found it. Thanks for correcting me

Comment: @OmarAl-Howeiti - Thanks, I will keep this in mind

Answer (score -1):

image of JS fiddle compiler for your question

[image]

I tried your js code with your HTML template in JS Fiddle (a javascript, HTML, CSS online compiler). But it is giving the desired output. I have attached a picture of it.

Generally, if an element is not found in the document then the querySelector returns null. So, maybe querySelector is not able to find your button element with class.

Please try something like :

```
const btn = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
```

or some other way like giving an 'id' attribute to your button and then trying to get the button with an id.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please do not answer that code is working.  Instead wait until [you have more rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) and comment on the question

Comment: Also please do not answer with pictures of code. You can click the `[<>]` snippet editor and post the code in there like I did for the poster